# Is $\ell^1$ is not closed inside $\ell^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I know that  $\ell^1\subset  \ell^2$ and both are banach spaces with respective norm.

But is $\ell^1$ closed or not closed wrt norm of $\ell^2$

I tried to find a counterexample to show given is not closed . But fail.Please Help me to construct an example or give hint to prove.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer Form hint provided by SamM

$a=(1/n)\in \ell^2$ but not in $\ell^1$

Not consider $a_m=(1/n^{1+1/m})\to a$ and each $a_m\in \ell^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do the $1/n$ example.
Consider the vector $(1, 1/2, 1/3, \dots, 1/n,0,0,0,\dots)$ where you chop it off after $n$ steps.  This is in $l^1$, as indeed any vector with finitely many nonzero coordinates is.  This converges in $l^2$ norm to the full vecor $(1,1/2,1/3,\dots)$, which is not in $l^1$.

Answer (score 1):

What sequences are square-summable but not summable? My go-to example of this the sequence whose terms are $1/n$. Now, if we raise this to the power $\alpha > 1$ then the sequence $(1/n^\alpha)$ *is* summable (so is in $\ell^1$). How can you use these facts to construct a counterexample?

Comment: Thanks for hint Please Check my updated answer in question

Comment: The exponent $1 + 1/m$ should probably be inside the parentheses since it applies to each term and not to the whole sequence. There are also some details to fill in to really justify all the claims I made.

Comment: Thanks I had edited